# Is an inline image with an HTML img tag in a post appreciated or not?

Tags: discussion, images

Today as I was reviewing suggested-edits, I came across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19228367). The OP just posted a link of the image as he/she didn't have enough reputation to post an inline image; that's fine. If I were to edit the post I would simply change the link to an inline-image having verifying the image.

But the editor changed the image with bare HTML markup using `<img>` tag within the paragraph rendering a mess, and the image was sticking out at the top of the paragraph.

I thought of editing it myself. *Reject and edit* would be the right choice there, but I ended up rejecting it. Later when I was reviewing my own reviews of the day, I found this edit had been approved!

I know using a small set of HTML tags are allowed in posts. Is this way of including image in post appreciated or not? Should I approve or reject in such situations?

Comment: There is no noticable difference between <img> and markdown. If you replace the img tag with `[![...][1]][1]` the result stays exactly the same. I, for myself, would have used "Improve Edit" and have moved the image to somewhere outside of the paragraph. I don't see any real problem with using img instead of markdown.

Comment: *Later when I was reviewing my own reviews of the day, I found this edit has been Approved!* Many reviewers approve all edits that add in an image the OP linked to, even if the image is unhelpful or even harmful. I find that if I want prevent a harmful image edit from going through I have to Reject and Edit. Otherwise you might as well Skip because two other reviewers will Approve it and it's just a wasted review.

Comment: So if the image is placed outside any paragraph, are both markdown and `img` tag equally appreciated?

Comment: @MunimMunna No, not equally appreciated: Markdown is favored over HTML whenever possible.

Comment: Oy. So many reviewers in the suggested edits queue need some talking to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it's not appreciated. An edit that makes a mess of the post should be **rejected**.

You chose the correct rejection reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Even when you can see that the edit was made with good intentions, you shouldn't approve it if the result comes out unreadable. If you feel like it (and want to prevent other reviewers from approving) then Reject and Edit, or when the changes were mostly useful then you might Approve and Edit.